# How to persist datasource for gridcolumn

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, webforms, datasource

With reference to the below mentioned code block (Designer- .ASPX), I am trying here to bind the inner gridview with a `List<>` at runtime. This `List<>` for the inner gridview is member of datasource of outer grid.

As you can see from the design, I want to bind the inner gridview with respective datasource only after user clicks on the embedded "+" image button.

I can find the inner gridview at button click but have no idea how to persist datasource for the same. Every column will have it's own `List<>` datasource, so I can't do it with session or view state.

Can anyone let me know how can I persist it with inner gridview and will bind it at runtime after user clicks on "+" sign?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lateral">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLateral" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Lateral") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Types">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton OnClick="imgExpandbtn_OnClick" ID="imgExpandbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Plus.png" />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTypes" Text='<%# Eval("Types") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvInner" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">     
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsActive").ToString())) ? "Y" : "N"%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I'm not real sure what you're trying to ask. What do you mean by "persist datasource"? Do you just want to know how to bind the inner gridview to a property of the row it's on when a button on that row is clicked?

Comment: @Telarian Yeah exactly that's what I need to know.

Comment: It would be very helpful is you would post the codebehind that is doing the work. I'm assuming you have handled "imgExpandbtn_OnClick" in the codebehind and have it doing the work of binding your inner grid view to the property of the row it's on.

Comment: @Telarian This is what I want to achieve. I havn't yet done this. In my code behind I want to bind inner grid view to the property of the column(not row) it is on after click of imgExpandBtn. But I am not able to do so. 
I was left with only option of setting datasource at design time using binding expression. It worked.
But now I have to write script to make that visible only after click of imgExpandbtn.

Comment: Well go ahead and add whatever codebehind you do have to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you fetching the data for inner grid along with outer grid? If yes then you should bind the inner grid when you are binding the outer grid i.e. set its data-source at design time using data binding expression. Then you should use java-script to show/hide the inner grid on click of expand/collapse button - not only this approach is simple to implement, it will save server trips on click of expand/collapse button.

Alternatively, you may choose to bind the inner grid only when the expand button is clicked. However, in such case, it does not make sense to pre-fetch & store the inner grid's data along with outer grid. In such scenario, you should fetch the inner grid's data when expand button is clicked (so you don't have to *"persist data-source"* because data will be fetched on-demand).

Comment: Actually data source of outer grid is a generic List and that list contains another List<> as its member. I have to bind this inner gridview with that inner List<>. So i don't have flexibility of fetching data only for inner gridview at runtime. Although your first option seems reasonable to me. I tried setting datasource design time as mentioned below. But inner gridview was not visible at all after i tried running the application. 
<asp:GridView ID="gvInner" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%# Eval("Lstbusinesstypes") %>'> 

if u have any code sample,please share

Comment: @Chat, assuming `Lstbusinesstypes` is a property that returns the list, said code should work. However, I am not certain where exactly columns are created because they are not present in markup (with `AutoGenerateColumns=false`) - perhaps that's the exact issue you are facing i.e. no columns to see. I would suggest you to add some columns in mark-up and check it out.

Comment: @VinayC Thanks a lot vinay. previously I was creating columns manually so had set autogenerate to false. later on I removed those columns but forgot to set it to true.

Comment: @Telarian yeah thats what I did. Had missed it for the first time.